# Jest instantiate manual mocked class with constructor params typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

How to instantiate manually mocked class in jest test file when it has constructor params?

I have a class that I created manual mock for in __mocks__ dir.

The class looks like this:

```js
export class MyClass {
    constructor(otherClass: MyOtherClassThatIDoNotWantToCreateInstaceOf) {}
}
```

I created manual mock in __mocks__ dir like:

```js
export MyClass = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {};
});
```

In my test file I do:

```js
import { MyClass } from '../my-class.ts';
jest.mock('../my-class.ts');

const myMockedClass = new MyClass(); // <- This requires constructor params. How do I tell typescript that this is mocked class and does not require constructor params?
```